# Support for 'short description' in package.xml / Bloom?

Tags: ros, package.xml, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way for Bloom to generate 'short descriptions' like what rosbuild used to do?

`manifest.xml` actually had an explicit `brief` attribute on the `description` tag, which seems to have been removed in `package.xml`. There are a number of packages in Groovy and Hydro (in Ubuntu) that have very long package descriptions, where a succinct short description would definitely help make things a bit more readable.

---

Update (2015-06-16): an initial implementation for this was added to Bloom with the merge of [ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/366](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/pull/366). Short descriptions (or *synopses*) are automatically extracted from the package manifest `description` field. Only the `rosdebian` generator supports this for now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112886/support-for-%27short-description%27-in-package.xml-/-bloom?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you talking about the description in the debs themselves?

I think this was removed from the `package.xml` spec because it was pretty much always not set or completely redundant to the description.

I could conceive that we use an approach like doxygen, where the first line, if followed by a new line character, is considered the brief.

In fact, the Debian guidelines for control files says the first line is considered the brief:

http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Description

The `bloom` template simply plops the whole description down in the `description:` field, so if you put a new line after the first line in your package's description, it should get processed by debs as the brief:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/blob/c2abfec5e4513a4e75909f14676a0371414da41b/bloom/generators/debian/templates/control.em#L12

There are some other interesting rules in there, which we could take advantage of, perhaps `bloom` could intelligently change the contents of the `package.xml` description to use some of those rules. If you think that is value, please open a ticket to that effect in `bloom`'s tracker.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-12-25**:
Yes, short descriptions in debs. I sort of expected Bloom to do that, seeing how it generates the control file. Am I right to think that Bloom strips any HTML tags out of the description tag before generating the control file? Are newlines preserved in that case? I'll open a ticket.